# Ruby 1.9.3 fails to install Mac OSX 10.6.8 Snow leopard

Tags: ruby

Mac osx having trouble installing ruby 1.9.3 through homebrew.

```
ld: warning: directory '/Users/Jage/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p286/lib' following -L not found
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2

config.status: creating ruby-1.9.pc
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-shared, --with-libyaml-dir
    CC = gcc
    LD = ld
    LDSHARED = gcc -dynamic -bundle
    CFLAGS = -O3 -Wno-error=shorten-64-to-32  -pipe 
    XCFLAGS = -include ruby/config.h -include ruby/missing.h -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT
    CPPFLAGS = -I/Users/Jage/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p286/include  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-darwin10.8.0 -I./include -I.
    DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -Wl,-flat_namespace  
    SOLIBS =
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I believe you probably need to update your "command line tools" either by updating xcode or installing the command line tools separately.

I would also highly recommend installing any version of Ruby via [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv). I believe it will solve your problems. It can be easily installed via homebrew.

It handles all the config options that you will need to set and also makes it easily possible to install multiple versions of ruby and easily switch between them on both a global or per directory basis.

For instance I regularly use 2.0, 1.9, and jRuby. Each project has its own dotfile (.ruby-version) generated when I instruct rbenv to use a specific version for that project's directory. When I cd to these directories rbenv automatically sets environment variables such that I get the correct version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I should have stated that i have ruby 1.8.7 installed
Rbenv installed, homebrew, and xcode installed which are all up to date on my current system im running or i beleive so, except the ruby

rbenv 0.4.0
xcode 3.2
ruby-build 20131122.1

would any of these gems cause me an error?

```
actionmailer (2.3.5, 1.3.6)
actionpack (2.3.5, 1.13.6)
actionwebservice (1.2.6)
activerecord (2.3.5, 1.15.6)
activeresource (2.3.5)
activesupport (2.3.5, 1.4.4)
acts_as_ferret (0.4.3)
capistrano (2.5.2)
cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
daemons (1.0.10)
dnssd (0.6.0)
fastthread (1.0.1)
fcgi (0.8.7)
ferret (0.11.6)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
highline (1.5.0)
hpricot (0.6.164)
libxml-ruby (1.1.2)
mongrel (1.1.5)
needle (1.3.0)
net-scp (1.0.1)
net-sftp (2.0.1, 1.1.1)
net-ssh (2.0.4, 1.1.4)
net-ssh-gateway (1.0.0)
rack (1.0.1)
rails (2.3.5, 1.2.6)
rake (0.8.3)
RedCloth (4.1.1)
ruby-openid (2.1.2)
ruby-yadis (0.3.4)
rubynode (0.1.5)
sqlite3-ruby (1.2.4)
termios (0.9.4)
xmpp4r (0.4)
```